# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, count

I'm trying to code a text analysis program, and one of the methods is supposed to write a file containing every word started by a certain letter and the number of occurences of that word, using a text file as input (`BufferedReader` and whatnot).

If input is: "O Pai Natal nao existe.
Mas o coelho da Pascoa existe
(e a Fada dos Dentes tambem)."

Output for e should be: EXISTE 2E 1
My code so far is as follows – I know I could have used a `HashMap`, but this is school work and we haven't learned that yet, so I'm trying to keep it within what was lectured –:

```
void WordList(char c, String file) throws IOException {

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ficheiro+".txt"));
    String[] words = null;
    int indexVector = 0;
    String[] wordAlreadyWritten = null;
    int indexVector2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i].charAt(0) == c) {
            words[indexVector] = texto[i];  /*error here */
            indexVector++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {   /*error here*/
        if (!wordWasAlreadyWritten(words[i], wordAlreadyWritten)) {
            out.write(words[i] + ": " + countNumberRepetitions(words[i], words));
            wordAlreadyWritten[indexVector2] = words[i];   /* error here*/
            indexVector2++;
        }
    }
    out.close();
}
```

I am also using some auxiliary methods as some may have noticed:

```
static boolean wordWasAlreadyWritten(String original, String[] array) {
    boolean was = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (original.equals(array[j])) {
            was = true;
        }
    }
    return was;
}

static int countNumberRepetitions(String word, String[] array) {
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (word.equals(array[i])) {
            contador++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

If someone can explain the `java.lang.NullPointerException` I'm getting and how to fix it, I would be very thankful. Also if someone has any idea on how to make my code better, it would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Initial both the String array

```
String[] words = new String[count];    // count any integer value 
String[] wordAlreadyWritten = new String[count];    // count any integer value
```

Due to which you are facing error.

Comment: I just cant seem to find a way to know the integer values to put in the dimension of the array

Comment: can u explain the use of two arrays so that i can help u

Comment: What I'm trying to do is use the "words" array to store every word, regardless of how many times and the other one to store the words just once, to serve as a means of comparison so I can find out how many times they are repeated in the "words" array. I'm sorry if it is confusing

Comment: words array will contain all the words of the file whereas wordAlreadyWritten will contain the duplicate/repeating word in the file.Correct ?

Comment: words array will contain all the words in the file whereas wordAlreadyWritten will contain just one instance of the word. For example, if the word "hello" is stored 3 times in "words", it will be only stored once in wordAlreadyWritten

Comment: 2 options are there first you can go with collection second you need to first find the count of words in the file and intial both the array with that number.You can use scanner to find the count of words

Comment: Ok that makes sense, just one more thing, if I initiate both the arrays with that number, wordAlreadyWritten will have tons of null entries, is that reasonable in terms of good programming?

Comment: Absolutley its not a good programming but if you cant go with collection and restrict to array then there is no any option.I will suggest you to go with collection.

Comment: hm ok, I will do it this way for school and then I will come back to it and do it again with collection. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Few Q's:

1. Where is text defined?
2. I do not see any memory allocation for 'words' String array. This will cause NPE.

Another suggestion:

You haven't studied HashMap but still you can write your own HashMap like implementation or closely resemble to that. I am sure you will learn something out of it.

Comment: text is defined in the constructor, it's basically a big string.

Comment: I am having trouble finding how much memory to allocate, can't use ArrayList so it's wrecking my brain

Comment: If you dont know the size of the Array, I suggest you to use LinkedList. If you cant use LinkedList, then I suggest you to simulate linked list where each node of linked list has bounded Array.